# incrementing id++ and saving new incremented value so it can be called and incremented again

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Values are added to Objects with keys.

The start value of id is set to 0. I am attempting to find a way to increment the id without resetting it to the given value of 0.

When the value is incremented, the new value(id) is pushed into Object, and this Object is then pushed in array (with all input values and id value, which is then later pushed into main localStorage). Then the new value(incremented id) is saved into into localStorage(just for id`s).

The problem arises with every new click requiring access to localStorage of id`s and looping it with a "for statement" to receive values (Every time a new id is created, the length of array. This results in an infinite loop on click.

A way to push incremented id into main array (all values) is needed while having access to the last value of incremented id, so it can be incremented again.

```
let testObjectOne = {
  //'title' is key and $title.val() is value of that key
  'title': $title.val(), 
  'typ': $typ.val(),
  'assign': $assign.val(),
  'files': $file.val().match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[0],
  'priority': $priority.val(),
  'category': $category.val(),
  'textField': $textField.val(),
  'end_date': $date.val(),
  'id':id,
};

let id = 0;
let array_id = [];
array_id.push(id);
let string_array_id = JSON.stringify(array_id);
localStorage.setItem('id' , string_array_id);

let savedId = localStorage.getItem('id'),
    array_savedId = JSON.parse(savedId);  
console.log(savedId);
console.log(array_savedId);

//looping id array 
for (let k = 0; k < array_savedId.length; k++){
  console.log(array_savedId[k]);
  //increments 0 to 1 , later on increments 0 to 1 and 1 to 2 and so on
  let newValue = array_savedId[k] + 1;
  //checks if new value is not matching to values in array 
  if (newValue !== array_savedId[k]){
    //then pushes new value into array creating new index
    array_savedId.push(newValue);
    //id inside testObjectOne is set to new value
    testObjectOne['id'] = newValue;
    //pushing testObjectOne into main array 
    let save_newValue_withID = localStorage.getItem('key'),
        array_s_nV_wID = JSON.parse(save_newValue_withID);
    array_s_nV_wID.push(testObjectOne);
    let string_newValue_withID =JSON.stringify(array_s_nV_wID);
    localStorage.setItem('key' , string_newValue_withID);
  }
}

let test = localStorage.getItem('key'), 
    array_test = JSON.parse(test);
array_test.push(testObjectOne);
let back_to_string = JSON.stringify(array_test);   
localStorage.setItem('key', back_to_string);
```

Comment: You can just save another value to localStorage, like localStorage.setItem('lastId', newValue), then when needed just retrieve lastId and increment it

Comment: so your advice is to save new incremented value into another localStorage , but then when i want to access it i need another loop because value is stored in array?? am i following this right??

Comment: The whole purpose of your code is to store items of unique id into an array right? Then generate an array of ids, as index for future lookup. If so, then there are simpler ways to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let testObjectOne = {
            'title': $title.val(),
            'typ': $typ.val(),
            'assign': $assign.val(),
            'files': $file.val().match(/[\/\\]([\w\d\s\.\-\(\)]+)$/)[0],
            'priority': $priority.val(),
            'category': $category.val(),
            'textField': $textField.val(),
            'end_date': $date.val(),
            'id': 0,
        };
        if (localStorage.getItem('key') === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('id', "0");
            let temp_Array = [];
            temp_Array.push(testObjectOne);
            localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(temp_Array));
        } else {
            let id_value = localStorage.getItem('id');
            let temp_array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
            id_value++;
            testObjectOne['id'] = id_value;
            temp_array.push(testObjectOne);
            localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(temp_array));
            localStorage.setItem('id', id_value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your case, it seems you have to keep of 2 arrays.

1. The main array that stores the Objects
2. The supporting array the store the ids of Objects only.

From the way you structure you loop, where you are looping array_savedId, and also adding new item into it during the loop, you will stuck in an infinite loop.

```
//looping id array 
for (let k = 0; k < array_savedId.length; k++){
   // somewhere in the loop, you are adding item into the array,
   // this is the recipe for infinite loop
   array_savedId.push(newValue);
}
```

If you just need unique id for the Objects, you can just get the last Object and increment the id. No need to loop the array at all.

```
// Load the object array
let save_newValue_withID = localStorage.getItem('key')
let array_s_nV_wID = JSON.parse(save_newValue_withID);

if (array_s_nV_wID.length == 0) {
  // Empty array, so we are adding first item
  testObjectOne['id'] = 1;
}
else {
  // Find the last object, increment the id
  let lastItem = array_s_nV_wID[array_s_nV_wID.length - 1]
  testObjectOne['id'] = lastItem['id'] + 1
}

// Save to storage
array_s_nV_wID.push(testObject) // <-- We will need this again later
let string_newValue_withID = JSON.stringify(array_s_nV_wID);
localStorage.setItem('key' , string_newValue_withID);
```

By now we are done with the main array, let work on the array of ids.
To avoid the 2 array goes out of sync for reasons such as we forget to update
ids array when we add/remove/edit the main array, and we keep carrying on with
the out of sync array, we will just rebuild the ids array based on the latest values of the main array

```
const newIdsArray = array_s_nV_wID.map(a => a.id)
localStorage.setItem('id' , newIdsArray);
```